# not able to send mails from linux ubuntu : 20.04 by using email mailutils (sendmail or mail keyword)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, scripting, shell-scripting

code :

```
subject="mail subject"
body="Hello World"
from="user@domain.com"
to="user@domain.com"
echo -e "Subject:${subject}\n${body}" | sendmail -f "${from}" -t "${to}"
echo "sent"
```

in main.cf
changed only below lines.

```
1. inet_interfaces = loopback-only
2. my hostname = outlook.office365.com
3.relay host = [outlook.office365.com]:587(i want to use 587 port)
```

**Error** :   status=bounced (host outlook.office365.com[ip] said: ip Client not authenticated to send mail.

Comment: Before using office365 as relay you need to pre-authenticate with your MS user and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the sasl_password parameter:

> smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
> smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
> smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
> smtp_tls_security_level = may
> header_size_limit = 409600

Inside the sasl_passwd file, you need to have this information:

> [outlook.office365.com]:587 username@you.com:SecurePassword

Finally, as postfix reads from a generated .db file from that sasl_passwd, you need to issue this command:

> postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

Restart the service and it should work.